# Github not working

Tags: git, github

I ran `git remote add origin git@github.com:meltzerj/dreamstill.git` which was fine, but when I run `git push origin master` I get the error:

```
ERROR: meltzerj/dreamstill.git doesn't exist. Did you enter it correctly?
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

However, the repository does exist: https://github.com/meltzerj/Dreamstill

whats going on?

Here's the contents of .git/config:

```
[core]
repositoryformatversion = 0
filemode = true
bare = false
logallrefupdates = true
ignorecase = true
[remote "origin"]
url = git@github.com:meltzerj/dreamstill.git
fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

Comment: can you paste the contents of your git config? its in appdir/.git/config

Comment: the "git remote add" command only adds the remote repo to your available repos, it doesn't validate that it exists.  The capital D is the issue.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your repository has a capital D in "Dreamstill".  Try:

```
git remote rm origin
git remote add origin git@github.com:meltzerj/Dreamstill.git
```